# C#.NET - Error Logging and Relative File Paths

Tags: c#, file, logging, relative-path

I have a class in C# that saves an error message in a log file in case of an exception.  Now I want to save the log file in the same folder containing the application's (in my case, a website) files.  I tried using Environment.CurrentDirectory however it is not retrieving the path to my website.  What can I do please to make use of a relative file path which points inside the website's directory?

Here is the class' code.  As you can see, the path is absolute.  I want to change it to a relative file path pointing to a folder in my website's directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)` returns the path where the current assembly resides. You could use

```
string logName = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "MyLogFile.log");
```

to create the log file name.

Question is really whether logging to the application's folder is permitted by the OS. Also, for Web-applications, the log file would be **publically visible and accessible through the web browser**.

Answer (score 2):

For a website use:

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/");
```

Comment: Please note that writing the log file to the web application's directory may be potentially dangerous. See my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Thorsten :)  I didn't know that.  Guess I better leave it as it is since my aim was to replace the debugging error page provided by SQL server with a custom error page and save the error message in a log file to be seen by the admin only.

Answer (score 0):

You might also could try this solution:

```
string path  = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "anotherFolder";
```

This would put the base dir of the app and a folder inside of the project!